# Find records with character followed by number in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to find records where a character (`S`) is followed by any number using a T-SQL query.

I have tried below query but it's not working.

Input will be: `ABC-1256-377 S203 yu 10`

Code:

```
select * 
from suppliers 
where PostalCode like 'S[0-9]%';
```

Comment: `select * from suppliers where PostalCode like '%S[0-9]%';` - leading wildcard

Comment: Thanks , its working, can you help how to check for include space in where clause?. means need to check for space before S

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a wildcard and space in condition:

```
select * from suppliers where PostalCode like '%[ ]S[0-9]%';
```